Uninitialized static variable is not being stored to bss segment
#include <stdio.h>
static int test;
int main () {
    return 0;
}

and after i compiled the file and check the size of bss segment nothing changed.
here's the ouput of the terminal after i check the bss segment size before adding the uninitialized static variable
C:\Users\User\Documents\Programming\C>size a.exe
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  14584    2556     480   17620    44d4 a.exe  

here's the ouput after i compiled with the uninitialized static var.
C:\Users\User\Documents\Programming\C>gcc test_static.c

C:\Users\User\Documents\Programming\C>size a.exe        
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  14584    2556     480   17620    44d4 a.exe   

ps. please teach me and correct my mistakes. im trying to learn c and i also want to learn what is happening behind the scene of the computer that is why im doing this...
i tried checking the data segment when i compiled the file with initialized static variable and it is adding up  to the data segment which is working, but still the uninitialized static variable is not adding up to the bss

Since the variable isn't used anywhere, the linker might think it's not worth storing? Or there's already enough space in the BSS to store it without the need to allocate more?

It might even be the compiler that omits the variable, since it can definitely notice that it's not used. Try printing its value in the main function and see if anything changes.

@Someprogrammerdude
i just tried to print it in the main func but and it is still not adding up to bss
#include <stdio.h>
static int i;
int main () {
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}


C:\Users\User\Documents\Programming\C>gcc test_static.c

C:\Users\User\Documents\Programming\C>size a.exe  
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  14584    2556     480   17620    44d4 a.exe   

C:\Users\User\Documents\Programming\C>

here's the output...

Try size a.o instead of size a.exe command. It may gives expected results.

@rechichi don't post code in comments, It's unreadable. Instead [edit] the question and put all relevant information into the question as properly formatted text.

Since the variable isn't used, any half-decent compiler will optimize it away. Do something like this to ensure that the variable gets allocated:
#include <stdio.h>
static volatile int test;

int main () 
{
  volatile int* ptr = &test;
  *ptr = 123;
}

volatile to ensure it isn't optimized away, address taken to ensure that it gets allocated in .bss and not in a register.

It's worth pointing out that volatile alone will not prevent variable removal, as compiler can still decide that variable isn't used. There must also be at least one access to volatile variable to make it impossible to remove.

You could omit the volatile from static volatile int test;. The volatile access through the pointer should be sufficient to ensure it is not optimized away.

@IanAbbott I don't think that is correct. And it depends on the C version actually and is a quality of implementation thing. Up to C17 a side effect is determined from 5.1.2.3 "Accessing a volatile object... are all side effects". This language bug has been fixed in C23 with "An access to an object through the use of an lvalue of volatile-qualified type is a volatile access. A volatile access to an object ... are all side effects".

@Lundin There is a still-open defect report DR 476 from 2015, but nothing seems to have been done about it until C23. I'm not sure how DRs affect the specification without a TC (technical corrigendum) to make it official.

@IanAbbott TC is something you attach to an existing publication, I believe. If the fix goes live as per C23, there need not be a TC. Although I'm far from an expert on ISO bureaucracy procedures. There's some rule about how many TC and addendums you are allowed to publish (3?) before you have to make a major revision.

@Lundin I can see why they wouldn't bother with a TC for C11 since C17 was already on the way in 2015, but I'm surprised the defect wasn't addressed in C17.

@GoswinvonBrederlow There is no 'uninitialized' error for any object with static duration. If they are not initialized explicitly, they will be initialized implicitly. For volatile int* ptr, the volatile qualifier is on the int referenced through the pointer, not on the pointer itself. I.e., it's a pointer to a volatile int, not a volatile pointer to an int.

@IanAbbott Ups, yes, the volatile is at a different place than I though.
